Laragon is blocking my access to MariaDB (local)
Trouble connecting my local mariadb after installing Laragon
- OS: Windows 11
- Laragon full V6.0
- Mariadb V11.2

Short description of the issue:
I am not able to connect to my MariaDB server (installed separately and located in program files) since I installed Laragon. Getting the error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'localhost' (10061)
More in-dept description:
Out of curiosity, I am switching from XAMPP to Laragon, now I already had a MariaDB installed from before and that is the one I always use for my projects.
In XAMPP this also created some problems, but changing the PORT in XAMPP's MySQL file seemed to solve the issue.
But when trying to connect to my MariaDB, after I changed the port on Laragon for the MySQL server, it still gave me a "Can't connect" error. Same situation if I simply turn off the MySQL server on the dashboard and keep it from running al together..
I am using port 3306 for MariaDB, and have set 3360 on the Laragon MySQL settings.

Note: I also checked if a local adress was already running on either ports (PS > netstat -a -o ). none were in use. before trying the following:

When trying to connect  (mariadb -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p) on port 3306, I get no access. But if I activate laragon's mysql and switch the port to 3360 (mariadb -h localhost -P 3360 -u root -p), I connect directly to that server.
When Laragon's MySQL is turned off, connection attempts on boths ports give the error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'localhost' (10061)
So I am assuming the laragon's MySQL is blocking my access to my MariaDB server?
What I would like to achieve:
Ultimately, what I want is to be able to continue using my MariaDB. Any tips?
Thanks!

Mysql can't block access to mariadb if mysql is not running. Even when mysql runs, it can only lbock mariadb if both are configured to listen on the same port and mysql was launched first. Is mariadb running at all?

@Shadow I see! Before Laragon, using the CLI command to connect worked fine, but after installing it, it still won't let me connect to Mariadb with the same command (and specifying the right port), not even when laragon is not running. I just closed the laragon process completely and did a netstat neither port 3306 or 3360 are in use. Still getting the error on my connection.

Is mariadb running at all? Based on the netstat report, mariadb does not run, so the can't connect error message is logical.

@Shadow I had a look, indeed my mariadb is not running at all, even after removing laragon, i'm also not even able to get it running. Could it be that the laragon installation corrupts my mariadb installation? or that there is a path variable or somehting that would break mariadb? I just tried this twice:
removing mariadb and laragon, reinstall mariadb (works), reinstall laragon (breaks mariadb) -> remove laragon (mariadb still not able to start up), debugging mariadb -> now mariadb works again. But once I reinstall laragon again, it breaks again

I can't tell you if laragon / mysql installation has impact on mariadb or not and frankly, that's not a programming question either. I would check mariadb / operating system logs and see if there are any errors there. If you cannot resolve those errors, then I would ask a question at the dba.stackexchange.com sister site of SO as SO is for programming questions only.

I am not 100% what exactly went wrong, but it seemed that something broke in my MariaDB setup when installing the Laragon packages.
The solution was the following:
After installing Laragon, change the port and/or disable your MySQL via the Laragon dashboard. After this, go to the uninsall wizard for MariaDB and start the process. On the first step, choose the option to "debug" which will update any corrupted files.
